# Squid, allow access to local servers not remote servers

Tags: squid

I have a small business network consisting of XP clients and linux servers, the XP clients use squid as a proxy server. I am trying to configure squid to allow some P.C.s access to internal network servers and external websites and others only access to internal network servers. So far I have :

> Allow   manager localhost
>       Deny    manager
>       Allow   purge localhost
>       Deny    purge
>       Deny    !Safe_ports
>       Deny    CONNECT !SSL_ports
>       Deny    denied
>       Allow   localnet
>       Allow   localhost
>       Deny    all

However a P.C. whose I.P address is in the denied list gets this error from firefox  :

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
>
> - This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
>           cookies
>     <

Instead of the web page that should show for denied P.C.s.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add an allowed acl containing the internal servers, with a type as "Web server addresses" :

> Allow   manager localhost
>       Deny    manager
>       Allow   purge localhost
>       Deny    purge
>       Deny    !Safe_ports
>       Deny    CONNECT !SSL_ports
>       Allow   Int_servers
>       Deny    denied
>       Allow   localnet
>       Allow   localhost
>       Deny    all